# Generating 3d-map for multiple images

Tags: image, height-map

I have multiple grayscale images, and am converting them into 3d-renders using the approach described here: http://johnflower.org/tutorial/make-mountains-blender-height-maps
That approach works fine for one or two images, but now I have 100-1000 images, which all should be processed using this or a similar method. Is there a method to apply the same method to all images and render them, one after another, after setting the initial parameters?

Comment: sounds like you need a script, and this seams easy to script. (whenever I have 100 of the same things to do, I automate it) Do you care about the 3D object after the render, or can it just render and move on to the next?

Comment: Ideally I would like to put all the results together to create a movie, i.e. at the moment I just am interested into the render, not the object itself

Comment: If the images are all the same size or proportions you could name them accordingly and then try and import them as an image sequence. You would only have to setup one plane with displacement and subdivision once, then render them all as if it was an animation, one terrain per frame. No scripting or custom solutions involved.